# Jquery Input type submit, event.preventDefault() don´t stop submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this jquery function, and the **event.preventDefault()** don´t work, Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

```
var wrBtnEnabled= function(btnId, btnName, btnFeedbackMessageId){
    $(btnId).click(function(event){

        var wrInput = "input[value='"+btnName+"']";
        var isSendFeedback = !$(document).find(wrInput).is(':disabled');

        if(isSendFeedback){
            event.preventDefault(); 

            $(btnFeedbackMessageId).click(); 
        }
    });
}

wrBtnEnabled('#HEBlocks_wt11_block_wtbtnTerminar', 'Actualizar', '#HEBlocks_wt11_block_wt1824_wtbtnFeedback');
```

HTML (The input that I want to stop submit if another input is enabled):

```
<input onclick="OsAjax(arguments[0] || window.event,'HEBlocks_wt11_block_wtbtnTerminar','HEBlocks_wt11$block$wtbtnTerminar','','__OSVSTATE,',''); return false;" type="submit" name="HEBlocks_wt11$block$wtbtnTerminar" value="Continuar" id="HEBlocks_wt11_block_wtbtnTerminar" tabindex="820" class="btnGeneral" style="align=center">
```

Thanks.
W

Comment: Seriously, what is this? where is `OsAjax`? doesn't make any sense to me..

Comment: I tj, this is a default for ajax btn in OS (Outsystems), thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of **preventDefault** try **return false** as shown :

```
if(isSendFeedback){
    return false;
    $(btnFeedbackMessageId).click(); 
}
```

`e.preventDefault()` will prevent the default event from occuring, `e.stopPropagation()` will prevent the event from bubbling up and `return false` will do both.

Comment: `e.stopPropagation()` isn't going to prevent from submission in the case of an `input` button... it doesn't have any child elements, from where an event will propagate to it?

Comment: @Kartikeya... i try your suggestion but don´t stop submit, and jump the "$(btnFeedbackMessageId).click();", Thanks

Comment: @Walter....strange..then why are you using `$(btnFeedbackMessageId).click()` inside if statement just put it inside else case instead..

Comment: @Walter..or just instead of `return false` ... try only `return`

Comment: @Kartikeya... i use $(btnFeedbackMessageId).click(), because I need to open a customized feedback message with information from the server if isSendFeedback is true. thanks

Comment: @Kartikeya i think understood the question, OP wants to revent form submission. or is it something else..? `preventDefault()` should do. like i said, stopping propagation isn't going to help if that's why you're suggesting `return false`..

Comment: @Kartikeya... I will change to have two buttons one verifies if sends a feedback message or click on another btn to submit (hidden btn).thanks